# Why do I get these unmanaged errors in managed code?

Tags: c#, c++, xaml, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

I have a Windows Store App and I can see on the Windows Developer dashboard that users are experiencing crashes. I don't understand the reports (mainly stack traces) as I'm not familiar with unmanged code (these apps are compiled to native code like C++ apps when they are published). I do, however, understand (or perhaps mistakenly think) that the errors that occur most frequently are errors that don't make sense. The app is an XAML/C# app with no unsafe code. And the main exceptions are:

> INVALID_POINTER_READ_c0000005_Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!DirectUI::UIAffinityReleaseQueue::DoCleanup

and

> INVALID_POINTER_READ_CONTEXT_MISMATCH_c0000005_Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!DirectUI::UIAffinityReleaseQueue::DoCleanup

Can anyone explain to me how can this type of errors happen in a purely managed code app?

Comment: Do you have code in fininalizers? (Functions that looks like `~YourClassName(){ ... }`) Also, please include the full error including the stack trace in your question.

Comment: With just the information given there's little we can do except speculate. I'd speculate, that you have event handlers attached while tearing down the UI.

Comment: @IInspectable Thanks. This might be happening (event handlers firing when their UI has been torn down) but all of these events have been enclosed in try-catch blocks. Besides, even if they weren't - C# should not allow pointers to be invalid. The errors should look something like 'you're accessing a disposed object'. Right?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Unfortunately, I can't post stack traces. About finalizers - ***I*** didn't write any finalizers, and there's no 3rd party code in the app. So only those that are part of the Windows Runtime.

Comment: As you noted, you are compiling to native code. There is no .NET in there any longer, once deployed. Even if there were, dereferencing a NULL pointer in C# would still cause an SEH exception (a native OS exception), that goes through native exception filters, implemented in the CLR to model .NET exceptions. Without seeing the stack traces, it's hard to tell, whether this causes a crash, or merely sets the stage. If you can't post stack traces I'd propose to close this question as off-topic.

Comment: @IInspectable Thanks. Your comment actually answered my question - Yes, C# _will_ have this type of exceptions. Note that I didn't ask for a solution for these specific crashes, I asked about C# vs Native code exceptions. You can transform your comment into an answer, or, if you still think this is off-topic, though I'm not sure that's true, just let me know and I'll delete the question. Thanks again.

Comment: @IInspectable Feel free to post your answer and notify me so I can delete my answer in favor of yours.

Comment: I don't think the information I have given in comments is sufficient to warrant writing it up in an answer. In fact, I still believe the question is not sufficient in itself to make it answerable. Your proposed answer isn't quite on spot either: It doesn't really matter, whether the application gets compiled to native code or not. Even when running inside the CLR, exceptions are native SEH under the hood. An uncaught exception will have native exception frames in its call stack just as well.

Answer (score -1):

According to a comment - this was based on a mistaken assumption.

When the app gets compiled into native code - it *will* get native-type errors.

Comment: I wish the downvoter would have left a comment, stating the reason. At any rate, this answer is a bit off target. It doesn't matter, whether you compile the application to native code prior to deploying it, or have the CLR compile it to native code on the target device. Either way, the application is executing native code. Since exceptions in the .NET framework use the native SEH infrastructure, you will see native exception code on the call stack when an application crashes due to an uncaught exception.

Comment: @IInspectable The native exceptions might happen, but as a .net developer I don't see them. When an app crashes using the CLR - the `CurrentDomain_UnhandledException` event handler shows me an `ExceptionObject` that can be transformed into a .net `Exception`. So I don't have to deal with native exceptions. I'm not disagreeing. Just explaining what matters to those like me that are used to dealing exclusively with .net. Thanks for the clarification, though.